# RequestMapping and sources path

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How can I handle all URL requests except resources mapping folder?

In this example I handled all paths (and that is what I want), but now I can not access the resourcess folder even when I set 
`​<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` inside `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String iallURL(HttpServletRequest request, Writer writer) {
    //read all paths
    return "some";
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: yes I added resources mapping

Comment: when you are access some path under /resources do you get "some" or stg else?

Comment: @nilgundag Op will probably get a view identified by `"some"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I can only recommend you change your `@RequestMapping` to have a value of `/`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String iallURL(HttpServletRequest request, Writer writer) {
    //read all paths
    return "some";
}
```

Another solution is to set an order for the resource handler.

```
<resources order="-1" mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

The `order` value is negative because the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` instances for the controller methods are by default `0`. The order is evaluated smallest first.

Comment: Can I use 'order' prop also for RequestMapping inside controller? is it possible?

Comment: @user Not directly, no. The handler methods are wrapped in these RequestMappingHandlerMapping instances that contain more informatio.  There is a solution for that but I don't have the details right now, I'm not home.  Also, please consider accepting the answer if it helped.